# Подскажите как с помощью лямбда выражения обработать определенную часть строки в коллекции?

Tags: java, java-stream, lambda

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list,
    "Joseph Smith", "Thomas Doyle", "Ronald Pratt", "Thomas Spencer", "King Lee",
    "Gregory Smith", "Leroy Zimmerman", "Lee Smith", "Michael Harrington", 
    "Lee Daniels","Eugene Williams", "Lee Terry", "Arnold Fowler", "Billy Harrison", 
    "Lee Bennett", "Lee Evans", "Ronald Diaz", "Leonard King", "Timothy Smith", 
    "George Lee", "King Mann", "Dean Wright"
);
    
list.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.contains("K") || s.contains("S"))
    .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("K")&&!s.startsWith("S"))
    .sorted().distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> Метод должен вернуть имена людей, чья фамилия начинается с K или S, в формате имя + первая буква фамилии, например "David Z.". Список должен быть отсортирован по алфавиту и состоять только из уникальных значений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для данных, представленных в формате `"{firstName} {lastName}"` можно отфильтровать слова при помощи `String::matches` и регулярного выражения типа `"\\w+ [KS]\\w+"`.  Соответственно, к отфильтрованным слов достаточно будет применить `String::substring`:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
    "Joseph Smith", "Thomas Doyle", "Ronald Pratt", "Thomas Spencer", "King Lee",
    "Gregory Smith", "Leroy Zimmerman", "Lee Smith", "Michael Harrington", "Lee Daniels","Eugene Williams", 
    "Lee Terry", "Arnold Fowler", "Billy Harrison", "Lee Bennett", "Lee Evans", "Ronald Diaz", 
    "Leonard King", "Timothy Smith", "George Lee", "King Mann", "Dean Wright"
);

List<String> fixed = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches("\\w+ [KS]\\w+"))
    .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ") + 2) + ".")
    .sorted()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());    

System.out.println(fixed); 
// -> [Gregory S., Joseph S., Lee S., Leonard K., Thomas S., Timothy S.]
```

---

Если имена состоят из трех и больше частей, но фамилией является последняя часть, регулярное выражение `".+ [KS]\\w+"` и поиск фамилии следует исправить (искать последний пробел при помощи `String::lastIndexOf`):

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
    "Joseph Smith", "Thomas Doyle", "Ronald Pratt Kimberly", "Thomas Spencer", "King Lee Roy Stapleton",
    "Gregory Smith", "Leroy Zimmerman", "Lee Smith Jacob", "Michael Harrington", "Lee Daniels","Eugene Williams", 
    "Lee Terry", "Arnold Fowler", "Billy Harrison", "Lee Bennett", "Lee Evans", "Ronald Diaz", 
    "Leonard King", "Timothy Smith", "George Lee", "King Mann", "Dean Wright"
);

List<String> fixed = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches(".+ [KS]\\w+"))
    .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(" ") + 2) + ".")
    .sorted()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());    

System.out.println(fixed);
// -> [Gregory S., Joseph S., King Lee Roy S., Leonard K., Ronald Pratt K., Thomas S., Timothy S.]
```

---

Ещё один вариант: вместо `String.substring` применить `String::replaceAll` для замены части фамилии на точку -- выглядит более "красиво":

```java
List<String> fixed = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches("(.+ [KS])(.*$)"))
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(.+ [KS])(.*$)", "$1."))
    .sorted()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо! пойду читать про matches и substring

Comment: @yaVodyanoy если вам помог ответ, принято отмечать его как решение, это "местная традиция". Для автора ответа это лучшая благодарность.

Comment: вот, кстати - и sorted и distinct - это же stateful не-терминальные операции. Не лучше ли сперва distinct, а потом sorted, чтобы сортировке меньше данных на вход пришло? Или наоборот - disticnt-у будет проще работать с отсортированным потоком?

Comment: @kami, это отдельный вопрос, на который тем не менее есть [ответ от мистера Holger'a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807329/13279831): [Java Streams: How to do an efficient "distinct and sort"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806467/) -- где доказывается, что лучше отсортировать, а потом применить `distinct` , так как в таком случае применяется некая оптимизация и не создаётся лишний `Set`.  Впрочем, это следует проверять для разных наборов данных.

Comment: @kami, ещё один [расширенный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804406/13279831) на вопрос о вычислительной сложности [What's the time complexity of Java Stream distinct().sorted()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798390/)

Comment: @NowhereMan благодарю, весьма познавательно

Comment: @NowhereMan, все проставил. Спасибо. Вопрос по красивому варианту: filter(бежим по всем символам пока не находим K/S) для чего нужно дальше до конца строки бежать (.*$)
В мапе тот же вопрос и плюс не понял как происходит изменение "$1." - то что нарисовалось у меня в голове (конец строки второго элемента(причем тогда здесь точка если это и так конец)) с заменой никак не вяжется. 
Буду признателен за ответ.

Comment: В скобках определяются группы: в первой группе все имена, пробел перед фамилией и K или S как первая буква фамилии, вторая группа `(.*$)` - остаток фамилии.  Затем в `replaceAll` второй аргумент `"$1."` означает, что оставляем только первую группу и после неё ставим точку.