# помогите написать код на java

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class HomeWork7 {
    /*
        ЗАДАНИЕ
        Напишите реализации для методов, используя StreamAPI
        В этих задания ЗАПРЕЩАЕТСЯ использование for и if
        Тело каждого метода должно начинаться с ключевого слова return
        (т.е. задания должны быть выполнены за одно выражение)
     */

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть список людей с фамилией или именем King
     */
    public static List<String> methodOne(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных фамилий (2 позиция в строке)
     */
    public static List<String> methodTwo(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных имен, начинающихся с L
     */
    public static List<String> methodThree(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных фамилий, начинающихся с W, отсортированный по алфавиту
     */
    public static List<String> methodFour(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть количество имен длинее чем 6 символов
     */
    public static Integer methodFive(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть суммарное количество уникальных имён и фамилий, длиннее 5 символов
     * P. S. Самостоятельно почитайте про метод flatMap()
     */
    public static Integer methodSix(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Метод должен вернуть имена людей, чья фамилия начинается с K или S, в формате имя + первая буква фамилии,
     * например "David Z.". Список должен быть отсортирован по алфавиту и состоять только из уникальных значений
     */
    public static List<String> methodSeven(List<String> names) {
        // Твой код здесь
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AntiCheat.run();
        printTestCase(KINGS, methodOne(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(UNIQ_SURNAMES, methodTwo(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(NAMES_STARTS_WITH_L, methodThree(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(SURNAMES_STARTS_WITH_W_SORTED, methodFour(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(NAMES_LONGER_THAN_SIX, methodFive(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(NAMES_AND_SURNAMES_LONGER_THAN_FIVE, methodSix(FULL_NAMES));
        printTestCase(NAMES_WITH_LETTER_SORTED, methodSeven(FULL_NAMES));
    }

    private static final List<String> FULL_NAMES = List.of(
            "Joseph Smith", "Thomas Doyle", "Ronald Pratt", "Thomas Spencer", "King Lee",
            "Gregory Smith", "Leroy Zimmerman", "Lee Smith", "Michael Harrington", "Lee Daniels",
            "Eugene Williams", "Lee Terry", "Arnold Fowler", "Billy Harrison", "Lee Bennett", "Lee Evans",
            "Ronald Diaz", "Leonard King", "Timothy Smith", "George Lee", "King Mann", "Dean Wright",
            "Lee Richards", "Arthur Smith", "Gregory Moore", "Larry Hall", "Patrick Moore", "Ben Smith",
            "Jose Smith", "Michael Parker", "Jeff Smith", "Larry Thompson", "Joel Smith", "Ivan Spencer",
            "Robert Anderson", "Lee Phillips", "Stanley Warren", "William Sanchez", "Jamie McDonald",
            "David Griffith", "Terry Hicks", "Larry Johnson", "Mike Fowler", "Ivan Shaw", "Lee Stevenson",
            "Lee Powell", "Larry King", "Lee Mitchell", "Robert Diaz", "John Fowler", "Todd Cox",
            "David James", "Willie Bryan", "Thomas Howard", "Ivan Stanley", "Paul Harper", "Robert King",
            "David Stanley", "Dale Fletcher", "Larry Mullins", "Arthur King", "Robert King", "John King",
            "Larry Coleman", "Anthony King", "Ivan Johnson", "Ivan Mann", "Michael Diaz", "Leroy Smith",
            "King Wagner", "David Stanley", "Ivan Willis", "Ivan Stewart", "Frank King", "Roland Jones",
            "Leroy Warren", "Rodney Bailey", "David King", "Randy King", "James Soto", "James Parker",
            "Bobby Stanley", "Leroy Cooper", "Michael Woods", "David Mann", "Lee Padilla", "Samuel Shelton",
            "Jesse Simmons", "Ivan Stanley", "Lee Gibson", "Bryan King", "David Brooks", "David Fowler",
            "Robert Fowler", "Ivan King", "Donald Thomas", "Leroy Ramsey", "Russell Diaz", "David Torres"
    );

    private static final List<String> KINGS = List.of(
            "King Lee", "Leonard King", "King Mann", "Larry King", "Robert King", "Arthur King",
            "Robert King", "John King", "Anthony King", "King Wagner", "Frank King", "David King", "Randy King",
            "Bryan King", "Ivan King"
    );

    private static final List<String> UNIQ_SURNAMES = List.of(
            "Smith", "Doyle", "Pratt", "Spencer",
            "Lee", "Zimmerman", "Harrington", "Daniels", "Williams", "Terry", "Fowler", "Harrison",
            "Bennett", "Evans", "Diaz", "King", "Mann", "Wright", "Richards", "Moore", "Hall", "Parker",
            "Thompson", "Anderson", "Phillips", "Warren", "Sanchez", "McDonald", "Griffith", "Hicks",
            "Johnson", "Shaw", "Stevenson", "Powell", "Mitchell", "Cox", "James", "Bryan", "Howard",
            "Stanley", "Harper", "Fletcher", "Mullins", "Coleman", "Wagner", "Willis", "Stewart",
            "Jones", "Bailey", "Soto", "Cooper", "Woods", "Padilla", "Shelton", "Simmons", "Gibson",
            "Brooks", "Thomas", "Ramsey", "Torres"
    );

    private static final List<String> NAMES_STARTS_WITH_L = List.of(
            "Leroy", "Lee", "Leonard", "Larry"
    );

    private static final List<String> SURNAMES_STARTS_WITH_W_SORTED = List.of(
            "Wagner", "Warren", "Williams", "Willis", "Woods", "Wright"
    );

    private static final List<String> NAMES_WITH_LETTER_SORTED = List.of(
            "Anthony K.", "Arthur K.", "Arthur S.", "Ben S.", "Bobby S.", "Bryan K.", "David K.",
            "David S.", "Frank K.", "Gregory S.", "Ivan K.", "Ivan S.", "James S.", "Jeff S.", "Jesse S.",
            "Joel S.", "John K.", "Jose S.", "Joseph S.", "Larry K.", "Lee S.", "Leonard K.", "Leroy S.",
            "Randy K.", "Robert K.", "Samuel S.", "Thomas S.", "Timothy S.", "William S."
    );

    private static final Integer NAMES_LONGER_THAN_SIX = 9;

    private static final Integer NAMES_AND_SURNAMES_LONGER_THAN_FIVE = 61;

    public static class AntiCheat {
        public static void run() {
            List<String> antiCheatList = new ArrayList<>();
            antiCheatList.addAll(FULL_NAMES);
            antiCheatList.addAll(KINGS);
            antiCheatList.addAll(UNIQ_SURNAMES);
            antiCheatList.addAll(NAMES_STARTS_WITH_L);
            antiCheatList.addAll(SURNAMES_STARTS_WITH_W_SORTED);
            antiCheatList.addAll(NAMES_WITH_LETTER_SORTED);
            antiCheatList.add(NAMES_LONGER_THAN_SIX.toString());
            antiCheatList.add(NAMES_AND_SURNAMES_LONGER_THAN_FIVE.toString());
            calcHash(antiCheatList);
        };

        public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
            char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
            char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
            for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
                int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
                hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
                hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
            }
            return new String(hexChars);
        }

        public static void calcHash(List<String> list) {
            String total = String.join("", list);
            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(total.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                System.out.println("AntiCheatCheck: " + bytesToHex(digest));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ignored) {}
        }
    }

    public static String constLen(String str, int len) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        while (len-- - str.length() > 0) sb.append(" ");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void printTestCase(List<String> exp, List<String> act) {
        System.out.println();
        Function<String, String> green = str -> "\u001B[34m" + str + "\u001B[0m";
        Function<String, String> yellow = str -> "\u001B[33m" + str + "\u001B[0m";
        System.out.println("Ожидание: " + yellow.apply(constLen(exp.toString(), 15)));
        System.out.println("Реальность: " + green.apply(constLen(act.toString(), 15)));
        System.out.print("RESULT ");
        if (Objects.equals(exp, act)) System.out.print("✅"); else System.out.print("❌");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printTestCase(Integer exp, Integer act) {
        System.out.println();
        Function<String, String> green = str -> "\u001B[34m" + str + "\u001B[0m";
        Function<String, String> yellow = str -> "\u001B[33m" + str + "\u001B[0m";
        System.out.println("Ожидание: " + yellow.apply(constLen(exp.toString(), 15)));
        System.out.println("Реальность: " + green.apply(constLen(act.toString(), 15)));
        System.out.print("RESULT ");
        if (Objects.equals(exp, act)) System.out.print("✅"); else System.out.print("❌");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

здравствуйте. Просьба написать код по заданию (написано в комментариях кода). Очень поможете, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Чтобы написат код надо объяснить что надо писать, а вопрос как писать код это уже не проблема. Надо привести код с примерной реализацией и пояснить проблему, почему этот код не работает или работает неправильно. Затем надо написать код с попытками исправить проблему. При этом могут возникать ошибки, которы тоже можно добавить в вопрос, также написать попытки исправить эти ошибки. В конечном итоге если после долгих усилий ничего не получится, то можно писать сюда.

Comment: "Просьба написать код по заданию" - это так говорят начальники своим подчинённым, а не задают вопросы. Здесь готовы помочь с выполнением задания, если у вас что-то не получается: код неверно работает, в нём ошибки, вам нужен алгоритм или подходящая библиотека. А делать за вас домашку здесь не будут.

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, **что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения данного задания достаточно использовать методы Stream API:

- [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), в котором следует указать требуемое условие для отбора,т.е. функцию-предикат, возвращающую булево значение.
- [`Stream::distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) для отбора "уникальных" значений.
- [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) для преобразования строки в имя или фамилию
- `Stream::collect(Collectors.toList())` -- стандартный способ, начиная с Java 8, возвращающий `ArrayList`, или [`Stream::toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()), добавленный в Java 16 и возвращающий неизменяемый список
- [`Stream::sorted`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) для сортировки потока данных по алфавиту

Для получения имён или фамилий могут использоваться разные методы `String`:

- разбитие при помощи `String::split` на массив строк и выбор при помощи индекса
- Поиск пробела и выделение подстроки `String::substring` + `String::indexOf`
- Удаление "ненужной" части при помощи `String::replaceFirst` / `String::replaceAll` -- нужно иметь представление о регулярных выражениях

Для отбора полного имени можно использовать `String::contains` или `String::matches` (с регулярным выражением) или даже `String::startsWith`.

Пример для решения седьмого задания можно было бы нагуглить на данном сайте:
[Подскажите как с помощью лямбда выражения обработать определенную часть строки в коллекции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1503445/386633)

---

```java
/**
 * Метод должен вернуть список людей с фамилией или именем King
 */
public static List<String> methodOne(List<String> names) {
    return names.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.contains("King"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных фамилий (2 позиция в строке)
 */
public static List<String> methodTwo(List<String> names) {
    return names.stream()
        .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных имен, начинающихся с L
 */
public static List<String> methodThree(List<String> names) {
    return names.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("L"))
        .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть список уникальных фамилий, начинающихся с W, отсортированный по алфавиту
 */
public static List<String> methodFour(List<String> names) {
    return names.stream()
        .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1))
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("W"))
        .distinct()
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть количество имен длинее чем 6 символов
 */
public static Integer methodFive(List<String> names) {
    return (int) names.stream()
        .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 6)
        .distinct()
        .count();
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть суммарное количество уникальных имён и фамилий, длиннее 5 символов
 */
public static Integer methodSix(List<String> names) {
    return (int) names.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
        .distinct()
        .count();
}

/**
 * Метод должен вернуть имена людей, чья фамилия начинается с K или S, в формате имя + первая буква фамилии,
 * например "David Z.". Список должен быть отсортирован по алфавиту и состоять только из уникальных значений
 */
public static List<String> methodSeven(List<String> names) {
    return names.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.matches("\\w+ [KS]\\w+"))
        .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ") + 2) + ".")
        .sorted()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[Онлайн демо GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/-7-wb0gs1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]